# Cant run or build apk?

Tags: android, apk, android-debug

When trying to run or build my apk in debug or release version i get a popup saying that my apk cant be installed because it wasnt signed properly. Im also getting this error shown at the same time

```
Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES]
```

So far i have:

- uninstalled everything related to android studio, sdk, .idea, .iml, and .gradle files
- run this `keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -alias android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 20000`
- ive tried making a new keystore

and i still cannot get it to run debug or release. Here is my app gradle

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
}
android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias 'myalias'
            keyPassword 'mypassword'
            storePassword 'mypassword!'
            storeFile file('E:/Android/keystore.jks')
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.intellidev.bitrichpro"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    afterEvaluate {
        tasks.matching {
            it.name.startsWith('dex')
        }.each { dx ->
            if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
                dx.additionalParameters = []
            }
            dx.additionalParameters += "--set-max-idx-number=60000" // default 60000
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    compile('org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:1.48') {
        exclude group: 'commons-io', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.9.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.orhanobut:dialogplus:1.10@aar'
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar:library:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile('com.coinbase.android:coinbase-android-sdk:1.0.1')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
}
}
dependencies {
}
```

Comment: when are you getting Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES] - what apk are you trying to install from where?

Comment: im using android studio. if i hit run ti simply make a debug build to my phone it comes up with that error, and when i try to build a release apk.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a release apk? You are using a release keystore that maybe does not exist, so you have to create it.

In Android Studio, you can create a release keystore in **Build** -> **Generate Signed Apk** -> **Create new...**

Debug keystore is automatically created with these default values:

**Key password:** android

**Keystore name:** debug.keystore

**Keystore password:** android

**Key alias:** androiddebugkey

Comment: ive tried creating a new keystore but it doesnt work.

Comment: Have you created it using Android Studio? Have you put it in right directory?

Comment: yes i used android studio. and yes its in the right directory.